# Onclick function with toggle classes not working

Tags: jquery

I have a a few `<article>` tags with classes, and two buttons showing and hiding certain articles based on their class - But it does not work

There are **two buttons**: `.latestClick` and `.mostViewedClick`. Each should be showing its own corresponding `<article>` tags: `<article>` tags with class `.latest` should show when clicking on `.latestClick` button, and same goes for `.mostViewedClick` button. Some `<article>` tags have bot classes, so when clicking on either of the two buttons, it should show.

jQuery

```
$('#featuredToggle ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('latestClick')) {
        $('article .mostViewed').toggleClass('hideArticle');
        $('article .latest').toggleClass('showArticle');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('mostViewedClick')) {
        $('article .latest').toggleClass('hideArticle');
        $('article .mostViewed').toggleClass('showArticle');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="featuredToggle">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="latestClick" href="#">Latest</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="mostViewedClick" href="#">Most Viewed</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="box_mini block feed">
    <article class="latest"> <a href="post.html"><img src="img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a href="post.html">SUV's</a></h4>

        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="mostViewed hideArticle"> <a href="post.html"><img src="img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a href="post.html">Bakkies</a></h4>

        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="latest mostViewed"> <a href="post.html"><img src="img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a href="post.html">Hatch Back</a></h4>

        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="latest mostViewed"> <a href="post.html"><img src="img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a href="post.html">Sedan</a></h4>

        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="latest"> <a href="post.html"><img src="img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a href="post.html">Coupe</a></h4>

        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hideArticle {
    display: none;
}
.showArticle {
    display: block;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Define "it does not work".

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Is it not doing *anything*?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle next time, good sir.

Comment: it means, that when I click on the buttons, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('article .mostViewed')` is looking for an article tag with a child element which has the class `mostViewed`. You need to remove the space to indicate that you are looking for an article tag with the class of `mostViewed` instead.

Aside from that, using toggle can get undesired effects, specially when someone keeps clicking the same link.

You can simplify you code drastically using jQuery [**show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/)/[**hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead, similar to:

```
$('#featuredToggle ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('latestClick')) {
        $('article.mostViewed').hide();
        $('article.latest').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('mostViewedClick')) {
        $('article.latest').hide();
        $('article.mostViewed').show();
    }
});
```

That way you also can't get undesired results with repetitive clicking on the same link.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zavr/) - Using `show()` and `hide()`

---

Comment: One more thing, whe I want to apply a background to the clicked elements, it also does not work: $(this).addClass('clickedStyle');

Comment: Using this style `.clickedStyle{background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x100");}` and `$(this).addClass("clickedStyle");` extending on the above DEMO seems to work. See [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zavr/6/) off course if you want to remove it from the other link/s you need to add something similar to `$(this).parents("li").siblings().find("a").removeClass("clickedStyle");` as well. See [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5zavr/7/)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answers, got it to works anyways...I just had to put !important for the attr in the .clickedStyle

Answer (score 3):

```
$('article .mostViewed').toggleClass('hideArticle');
$('article .latest').toggleClass('showArticle');
```

You have a space in your selector that does not belong.

```
$('article.mostViewed').toggleClass('hideArticle');
$('article.latest').toggleClass('showArticle');
```